# c# - fastest way to insert value from DataReader into DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, datagridview, datatable

I need to load the data from SQLite, then show the data in DataTable to display in DataGridView. The current approach I am using is read the data from DataReader, then loop through reader.Read() to create each DataRow.

The performance is slow for above method because I have 600k rows of data row. I had tried to use dataTable.Load(reader), but it is even slow then previous. Is there any fastest way to add the data from SQLite into DataTable.

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
  DataRow dRow = dataTable.NewRow();
  dRow[''] = reader[''].ToString();
  ......
  ......
  ......
  dataTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
}
```

Comment: What have your google results told you?

Comment: so far google told me to use dataTable.Load(reader), but as I mentioned it is slower than previous

Comment: if you are trying to load too much information, try to use paging in your stored procedure and get only the required no of rows from database

Comment: I know 600k rows are too much and I dont think client can view all. I wish to do paging,but client prefer to show all data in one page. The reason as simple as because their legacy system show everything and it is pretty fast.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @vendettamit, edited to include my code, Thank

Comment: To start with you should not be in WinForms.  In WPF I would load the 10K, display, and then go back for the rest in background process.

Comment: @Paparazzi: WinForms has got nothing to do with OP's problem. It is those 600K records that is slowing down his app, and it will do the same thing in WPF too. If you're suggesting WPF for paging, that can be done in WinForms as well.

Comment: @dotNET  My suggestion is clear.   And you have your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a option which you might not care.

What you're doing now is, one by one, inputing 600,000 value into each column of row(of dataTable) and if columns of new row are completely inserted, the new row is added to the DataTable.

Your code inside while reading loop seems just constructing a new row and adding it to dataTable.

If you don't need to manipulate each value while reading loop which means you only need datas as they're,

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(commmand);

da.Fill(dataTable);
dataGridView.ItemsSource= dt.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `Adapter` above? Adapters are supposed to replace low-level reader loops. If you do use `Adapter.Fill()`, you should remove the `reader` object as well as the loop from above code.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough. What I'm saying is that you either use a `DataAdapter` or you use a `SqlCommand` + `SqlDataReader`. You do not use both of them.

Comment: @dotNET, I thought OP might want some possibility to manipulate while reading..I knew but, of course, I appreciate your valuable advice.